# create android, iOS libraries from python, including dependencies

Tags: python, android, ios, compilation

We working on a project which involves ML/AI integration to the native mobile application. We are programing our ML/AI code in python. Python code has dependencies, that we need to include in our mobile application.

We have tried with [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) but they only create .apk files and apk files can't be called from other apks. So, we need to create libraries that can be included in the android and ios projects.

Also, we tried [chequopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/) but that doesn't support [mediapipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/) which is in heart of our implementation.

Any guidance in that direction will go long way for us.

Answer (score 1):

If your app was entirely self-contained in python including dependencies using [recipes](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/#) should be possible. If rewriting the native app is not an option maybe one idea is to serve the ML over an HTTP API running on a local server (eg flask). Quite cumbersome as users would need to install two apps